# How can I compare a string I input and compare the string in text file by using a vector Java?

Tags: java, string, vector

Assume the text file contains:

> He is a boy .
>   She is sick .
>   Ali is playing .
>   We are eating .
>   The dog is barking .
>   He and his brother are running .
>   He is playing .

And I want to compare the string by separate into below:

> He is
>   is a
>   a boy
>   boy .
>   She is
>   is sick
>   sick .

and so on.

I have put all the word above into a vector. How can I compare with the string I input?

Assume the way is like this:
Input String: `He is a boy .`

`He is` from the input string, and want to compare with vector by finding out how many   time it occur in the vector.

This is what I have tried:

```
try{
    // Open the file that is the first 
    // command line parameter
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");

    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    int lineNum = 0;

    Vector text= new Vector();
    Enumeration vtext = text.elements();

    //Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        // Print the content on the console
        //System.out.println (strLine);
        lineNum++;

        String[] words = strLine.split("\\s+");

        //System.out.println(words[0]);
        for (int i = 0, l = words.length; i + 1 < l; i++){
            text.addElement(words[i] + " " + words[i + 1]);
        }       
    }
    String str23 = "She is"; 
    while(vtext.hasMoreElements()){
        String yy = "He is";
        if(text.contains(yy)){
            System.out.println("Vector contains 3."); 
        }
        System.out.print(vtext.nextElement() + " "); 
        System.out.println(); 
    }       
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println(lineNum);

    //Close the input stream
    in.close();
}catch (Exception e){  //Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also, if this is homework you should add the correct tag.

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Side note:  `Vector` usually isn't the best list class to use these days, because it does synchronization that's usually not needed.  You probably ought to use an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` instead.

Comment: If I want to use vector. Then if I use `text.contains(yy)` but it will keep print the thing I put in. How can I just print 2 times since it only occur 2 time in the text.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a waste of time to answer - but here goes:

I changed your loop to be:

```
String str23 = "She is"; 
int countOfHeIs = 0;
String yy = "He is";
while(vtext.hasMoreElements()){

    if (vtext.nextElement().equals(yy))
    {
        countOfHeIs++;
    }
    if(text.contains(yy)){
        System.out.println("Vector contains 3."); 
    }
    System.out.print(vtext.nextElement() + " "); 
    System.out.println(); 
}       
System.out.println(text);
System.out.println(lineNum);
System.out.printf("'%s' appears %d times\n", yy, countOfHeIs);
```

the method `contains` does not count appearances - it only gives you a yes/no indication - you should count the amount of apperances yourself.

This is not the most optimal solution for your problem - since a `Vector` is not the best choice here. I would recommend using a `Map<String,Integer>` to keep track of the number of occurrences of each string.